# How to show Precession, Recall and F1-Score?

Tags: python, metrics, precision-recall

I am currently in the process of displaying precision, recall and fscore. Now my question is how do I do this? What I tried is the following:

```
num_users, num_items = train_mat.shape
user_input, item_input, labels = get_train_samples(train_mat, num_negatives)
val_user_input, val_item_input, val_labels = get_train_samples(val_mat, num_negatives)
.
.
.
history = model.fit([np.array(user_input), np.array(item_input)], np.array(labels), 
                 epochs=EPOCHS, verbose=VERBOSE, shuffle=True, batch_size = BATCH_SIZE,
                 validation_data=([np.array(val_user_input), np.array(val_item_input)], np.array(val_labels)),
                  callbacks=CALLBACKS)
.
.
.
# Precision, recall and fscore
from sklearn.metrics import precision_recall_fscore_support, confusion_matrix, roc_curve, auc
precision, recall, fscore, _ = precision_recall_fscore_support(y_test, y_pred, average='weighted')

print('Precision, recall, and F1 score, averaged and weighted by number of instances in each class:')
print('precision: {}'.format(precision))
print('recall: {}'.format(recall))
print('f1 score: {}\n'.format(fscore))

precision, recall, fscore, _ = precision_recall_fscore_support(y_test, y_pred)

print('Precision, recall, and F1 score, per class [0 1]:')
print('precision: {}'.format(precision))
print('recall: {}'.format(recall))
print('f1 score: {}'.format(fscore))


cm = confusion_matrix(y_test, y_pred)
sns.heatmap(cm, annot=True)
```

Unfortunately I don't know how to get `y_test` and `y_pred`. How do I get these values?

Comment: You get X_test, y_test from your dataset. You should keep some data from your dataset to test on your trained model. So, after the training is then you predict X_test on your model and get y_pred. Finally, you match y_test (which is the truth value) with y_pred (Prediction of your model).

Comment: Thanks, that means I have to remove data at the beginning (meaning test data). After that I also do `test_user_input, test_item_input, test_labels = get_train_samples (test_mat, num_negatives)` and with these values ​​I call `model.predic`

Comment: Depending on your dataset structure, I think so. All you have to do is just split your dataset into two subset that is conventionally called as `train` and `test` data.

Comment: Do I then have to enter the test data into the model again? :)

Comment: You will only use it when the training period is over to measure different scores of your model. You may check this [notebook](https://github.com/afifaniks/BanglaMusicGenreClassification/blob/master/nn_model_keras.ipynb) for example. Please notice how I have split dataset in block `In [15]` and then again used `test` data in block `In [27]` to generate confusion matrix. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

you shall have `y_test` as the test set to test your model and if you dont have such a set you can use sklearn train test split for getting a training set and a test set. Here is the link for how to use it:
[sklearn traiin test split](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.model_selection.train_test_split.html)

and when you will have your test set you will do this to get `y_pred`:

```
y_pred = model.predict(y_test)
```